# What's the inferred name of variables in argparse in conflicting cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have noticed that `argparse` uses a rather "mystic" way of creating the variables in the parser. I know that the names of the variables are usually easy to [infer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest):
it's the stripped version of long or short option (without the `--` or `-` respectively).

Also all hyphens (`-`) becomes underscores (`_`) to become legal variable names.

But that leaves me with a question about conflicting cases (I know it's an extreme case but the inferring part it's a bit mysterious to me). For example the program:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A simple test about var names")
parser.add_argument("--max-value", type=int, help="the maximum value", metavar="Maximum-value")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--max_value", action="store_true", help="Whether to the use maximum value", dest="max1")
args = parser.parse_args()
print("max_value {}".format(args.max1))
print("max-value {}".format(args.max_value))
```

uses apparently two very similar options (`--max-value` and `--max_value`) which lead to the same inferred variable `max_value`. If either of the options was missing the variable would be `max_value` without ambiguity.

But when both are present, apparently `--max_value` gets the trophy variable `max_value` and the second one (`--max-value`) gets what? I haven't been able to find what's the second variable.

So, to access it I must define a variable explicitly with `dest` option? How do I get list of the names of variables available? The funny thing is that if I use `dest=` for the `--max_value` option then `--max-value` gets the expected variable `max_value` while `--max_value` gets the non inferred one (in my case `max1`)!

I know also that [metavar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar) has nothing to do with the actual variable name but only affects the display in help.

Edit:

Adding some information from the @Martijn Pieters answer:

If I am getting it write if no `dest` is applied the parser follows the general rule which states that an implicit `dest` is applied. The same in my case `dest="max_value"`.

So,

```
parser.add_argument("--max-value", type=int, help="the maximum value")
```

is exactly the same as:

```
parser.add_argument("--max-value", type=int, help="the maximum value", dest="max_value")
```

internally.

But, then the following code snippets should produce different results which it does not:

```
# parserv1.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A simple test about var names")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--max_value", action="store_true", help="Whether to the use maximum value", dest="max_value")
parser.add_argument("--max-value", type=int, help="the maximum value", metavar="Maximum-value", dest="max_value")
args = parser.parse_args()
print("max-value {}".format(args.max_value))

>>>python parserv1.py -m --max-value 3
```

> max-value 3

```
# parserv2.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A simple test about var names")
parser.add_argument("--max-value", type=int, help="the maximum value", metavar="Maximum-value", dest="max_value")
parser.add_argument("-m", "--max_value", action="store_true", help="Whether to the use maximum value", dest="max_value")
args = parser.parse_args()
print("max-value {}".format(args.max_value))

>>>python parserv1.py -m --max-value 3
```

> max-value 3

Both just print the value of `max_value` as `int` independently of the order they are declared.

So, `int` option have higher precedence than binary (i.e. flags)? Are option types important in these cases?

P.S. 
I am using python 3.6.3 and since it might be a version issue I wanted to mention it.

Comment: I would appreciate also to get a reason for downvoting also

Comment: `python parserv1.py` (without args) gives different results (default) depending on the order in which the Actions are defined.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. It seem that the first defined gets the variable in that case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no conflict here; for both `--max-value` and `--max_value`, the library simply generates the *exact same destination name*. Multiple options writing to the same `dest` destination name is perfectly valid; the last option used on the command line wins in that case:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("--option1", dest="foo")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--option1'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument("--option2", dest="foo")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--option2'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--option2', 'bar', '--option1', 'baz'])
Namespace(foo='baz')
```

Here `--option1 baz` wins because `--option1` was used last on the command line.

Note that any defaults are applied before command-line parsing; the *first* registered option default value wins. Then the command-line is parsed and if only *one* of the options is used, then naturally the action associated with that option wins.

It is up to you to pick non-conflicting destination names. Not picking option strings that are easy to confuse is also a good idea.

If you were looking for a formal set of rules on what `dest` name is generated for a given optional argument, see the [`dest` option documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest):

> For optional argument actions, the value of `dest` is normally inferred from the option strings. `ArgumentParser` generates the value of dest by taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial `--` string. If no long option strings were supplied, `dest` will be derived from the first short option string by stripping the initial `-` character. Any internal `-` characters will be converted to `_` characters to make sure the string is a valid attribute name.

---

Multiple options all writing to the same `dest` destination name is useful for supporting old, deprecated names for a given option:

```
parser.add_argument('-n', '--new', dest='new', help="New hotness option")
# old name for the new hotness option, now deprecated but still supported
# argparse.SUPPRESS ensures it is no longer listed in the help output
parser.add_argument('-o', '--old', dest='new', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

So using `-o` or `--old` on the command line has the exact same effect as using `-n` or `--new`; the same destination name is set on the namespace.

Comment: Additional info: If the arguments have default values, but none is specified, the first wins (even if its default value is None).

Comment: @YSelf: indeed; the search for a default for a given `dest` stops at the first matching action, in order of registration.

Comment: So, how does this answer my question of how is the conflict resolved? What's the second variable name in that case?

Comment: @Eypros: I state at the top of my answer: *The library simply generates the exact same destination name*

Comment: @Eypros: so you have two options that both write to `max_value` as the destination, unless you manually specify a different `dest` value.

Comment: So, the short answer is the conflict is not resolved automatically and we miss an option?

Comment: @Eypros: it is not seen as a conflict by the library. If the end user uses *both* command-line switches, then the last one used on the command line wins and determines the value.

Comment: No, it's not (the last does not always wins). I edited my post

Comment: I am using 2 option: `-m` meaning `--max_value` and `--max-value`. Where is 1 option only?

Comment: @Eypros: ugh. The code is rather complex, and I was tired and misread. Defaults are applied in registration order (first action wins), command-line options are applied in the order they are listed on the command line (last option on the command-line wins).

Comment: @Eypros: so `--max-value 3 -m` results in `Namespace(max_value=True)`.